# How does bundler work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

This question is about bundler,rubygems & how does it figure out which method I am calling. Its quite long, so please bear with me.

As per my understanding, Bundler is a dependency management tool for managing gems for ruby. It install all the gems & their dependencies listed in the `Gemfile`.

The question I want to ask can be best illustrated by an example. so here--> In my rails app I am doing this in my controller:-

```
module SurveyorControllerCustomMethods
  def create
    super
  end
end
class SurveyorController < ApplicationController
   include Surveyor::SurveyorControllerMethods
end
```

Here, I am doing two things:

1. Include `SurveyorControllerMethods` from Surveyor gem.
2. As I have used *super* here, it would call `create` method from
   `SurveyorControllerMethods` which works just fine but I do not
   understand it.

and the gem is installed at

```
$ bundle show surveyor
/home/gaurish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/surveyor-0.22.0
```

Which surprisingly is NOT present in ruby's [`$LOAD_PATH`](https://gist.github.com/2586848). so question is:

1. how does it even work?
2. Install a gem using bundler, what happens behind the scenes during install?
3. there are some gems ex `jquery-rails` for which we even don't have to include/call them in our code & yet, jQuery JavaScript file is automatically included. I know its not magic, so how does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They key is actually in how Rails is set up out of the box.  Which is also one of the reasons Rails is so slow to start on larger projects.[1]

In boot.rb you'll find:

```
require 'bunder/setup'
```

and at the top of application.rb you'll find:

```
Bundler.require(:default, :development)
```

This last method call looks back to your Gemfile, then iterates *all* of the gems that are in the given groups (`:default` and `:development` in the above).  It then takes a stab at determining what the default file is that should be loaded, which is typically the gem name, but can also be specified by a `:require` option.  Bundler has some built-in naming convention exceptions too, such as the handling of "-" instead of "_".

Bundler then just loads the primary file for the gem, which in turn (typically) loads the files inside the gem.

The `'bundler/setup'` file performs `Bundler.setup`, which takes care of the load path.  It prepends (unshifts) to the `$LOAD_PATH` for each gem.  The actual information about what those loads paths should be comes from rubygems.

Take a look at the source in:

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/setup.rb
https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/runtime.rb

[1]: When you start a new Rails project, you'll probably find it doesn't get so slow over time if you delete the Bundler.require line and just require gems as they are needed.

Comment: I can't find `Bundler.setup(:default, :development)` in `config/boot.rb` or `config/application.rb`?

Comment: Oops, I apologize, it requires `bundler/setup`, which is doing that indirectly https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/setup.rb